# A simple rate limiter in php and memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I'm trying to make a simple rate limiter, based on the comments from [here](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/):

```
function set_session_rate_limit($memcache, $name, $user_session, $time)
{
   $memcache->add($name . $user_session, 0, $time);

   return $memcache->increment($name . $user_session);
}


set_session_rate_limit($memcache, 'login_fail_', $user_session, 300);

function get_session_rate_limit($memcache, $name, $user_session)
{
   return $memcache->get($name . $user_session);
}


var_dump(get_session_rate_limit($memcache, 'login_fail_', $user_session));
```

Why does the above code return bool(false)?

Comment: Because `$memcache->get` is returning false.

Answer (score 3):

this might not be appropriate but I believe a rate limiter should be as bare as possible. Below I have tried to a simple session-based limiter.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    const cap = 3;//Max http requests a host can make
    const period = 5;//the period in which it limits,60 means 1 minuts
    $stamp_init = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['FIRST_REQUEST_TIME'] ) ){
            $_SESSION['FIRST_REQUEST_TIME'] = $stamp_init;
    }
    $first_request_time = $_SESSION['FIRST_REQUEST_TIME'];
    $stamp_expire = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $first_request_time )+( period ) );
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['REQ_COUNT'] ) ){
            $_SESSION['REQ_COUNT'] = 0;
    }
    $req_count = $_SESSION['REQ_COUNT'];
    $req_count++;
    if( $stamp_init > $stamp_expire ){//Expired
            $req_count = 1;
            $first_request_time = $stamp_init;
    }
    $_SESSION['REQ_COUNT'] = $req_count;
    $_SESSION['FIRST_REQUEST_TIME'] = $first_request_time;
    header('X-RateLimit-Limit: '.cap);
    header('X-RateLimit-Remaining: ' . ( cap-$req_count ) );
    if( $req_count > cap){//Too many requests
            http_response_code( 429 );
            exit();
    }
```

Comment: It can be bypassed by just cleaning session cookies, right?

Comment: Considering the fact, cookies with PHP are associated with unique PHPSESSID. Yes this would be bypassed on cleaning the cookie. Also, this code is definitely not the best solution but a quick implementation. I wonder using mac would be more precise and something not be changeable/bypassed by the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

[Read](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.add.php) `add()` method syntax:
`bool Memcache::add ( string $key , mixed $var [, int $flag [, int $expire ]] )`
you have
$key = $name . $user_session
$var = 0
$flag = $time
so, before $time write null (flag).
`$memcache->add($name . $user_session, 0, null, $time);`
And I think method `set` will be more useful here.

Comment: This is memcacheD not memcache